# regular expression that preseves one or more leading underscore

Tags: python

I need the regular expression that preserves one or more leading underscores

```
import re 
function_name=[]
def function_renamer(code):
  functions= re.findall(r'def\s+[\w.-]+', code)
  for x in functions:
   x= x.replace('_','')
  print(x)

function_renamer('def _add_two_numbers(a, b)')
```

this returns

```
def addtwonumbers
```

but what I need is `_addtwonumbers`

Comment: It will not give him what he asks for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` in a bit different way, by using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). This way you can replace all `_` ***except*** the first one:

```py
 import re

def function_renamer(code):
    functions = re.findall(r'def\s+[\w.-]+', code)
    for x in functions:
        x = re.sub(r'(\w)_', '\g<1>', x)
        print(x)

function_renamer('def _add_two_numbers(a, b) def a_d_d(a, b)')
```

This will print:

```
def _addtwonumbers
def add
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function_renamer(code):
    code = code.replace(" ", "!")
    code = code.replace("_", " ")
    code = str(code.replace(code.split(" ")[1], "_" + code.split(" ")[1]))
    code = code.replace(" ", "")
    code = code.replace("!", " ")
    print(code)
```

It will work for `('def _sub_two_numbers(a, b)` and `'def _add_two_numbers(a, b)'`

Comment: I think this is your only option in this case